# Is there a way to map a Retrofit @QueryMap to some object for a Spring Rest Service?

Tags: spring, retrofit2

The client interface looks like this

```
   @GET("v3/users/posts")
   Call<User> loadPosts(@QueryMap Map<String,String> data);
```

The RestController should then process the map of query data returning the user's post. There are multiple parameters that can be put in the map as shown in the UserService.findUserPosts().  Is it possible to use a map to pass data to the Spring Rest controller? The restriction I have is this is inherited from code using @Query parameters but it has now grown to quite a number and a query map would limit the changes on the client. I would be really grateful for some feedback. Many thanks

```
 @RestController 

 public class UsersController{

         @RequestMapping(value = "/user/posts", method = RequestMethod.GET, 

               produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

         public ResponseEntity<User> getUserPosts(.......What here) {

         List<Posts> posts = userService.findPostsBy(id,postKey,offset,when);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.  For anyone in the future who wants to do what I am doing , simply provide Request parameters for every key pair in the map

i.e @RequestParam("id") String id,
@RequestParam("postKey") Long, @RequestParam("offset") etc.